# "The server responds with a HTML page, but an XML document was expected." Docuware

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to retreive some documents in Docuware Platform version 7.7 using the code below :

```
var docuwareEntity = new DocuwareEntity
            {
                Id = 6,
                Chapitre = "Chapter",
                SousChapitre = "Some (SousChapitre)",
                FileCabinetId = "FILE_CABINET_ID",
                Type = "DocumentType"
            };

            var dialogExpression = new DialogExpression
            {
                Operation = DialogExpressionOperation.And,
                Condition = new List<DialogExpressionCondition>
                {
                    DialogExpressionCondition.Create("CHAPITRE", docuwareEntity.Chapitre),
                    DialogExpressionCondition.Create("SOUS_CHAPITRE", docuwareEntity.SousChapitre),
                    DialogExpressionCondition.Create("TYPE_DOC", docuwareEntity.Type)
                },
                Count = 100,
                SortOrder = new List<SortedField>
                {
                    SortedField.Create("DATE_DOC", SortDirection.Desc)
                }
            };
            var serviceConnection = ServiceConnection.Create(new Uri("http://simu/DocuWare/Platform/"), "dmina", "myPassword");


            var fileCabinet = serviceConnection.GetFileCabinet(docuwareEntity.FileCabinetId);

            var dialogInfoItems = fileCabinet.GetDialogInfosFromSearchesRelation();

            Dialog dialog = null;

            foreach (var dialogInfo in dialogInfoItems.Dialog.Where(dialogInfo => dialogInfo.GetDialogFromSelfRelation().DisplayName == "Admin"))
            {
                dialog = dialogInfo.GetDialogFromSelfRelation();
                break;
            }

            var documentsResult = dialog.GetDocumentsResult(dialogExpression);
```

But I've got this exception on `dialog.GetDocumentsResult();`

```
DocuWare.Services.Http.Client.HttpClientRequestException: The server responds with a HTML page, but an XML document was expected.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
```

Has anyone an idea what could cause this excpetion please ?
I'm using DocuWare.Platform.ServerClient package version 13.12.1 with .NET Framework 4.8

I have performed as it is described in [Docuware documentation](https://developer.docuware.com/dotNet_CodeExamples/basic_operations/b8b6ddf4-fee5-4b5c-84cc-046895c8aa5a.html) but it is not working.

Comment: Usually, a web server will respond with a standard HTML page when an endpoint it not available (404 error), or your credentials aren't correct (403).  If you look at the HTML, what error is given?

Comment: the return HTML page contains this :
**This page allows you to execute a dialog expression query.**
 _The XML syntax of a query can be found at this schema._

_To execute a query type a query XML in the following box and press "Submit"._

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue that may or may not be related to your error. I was receiving a 422 status code response in my scenario. The issue had to do with the () parenthesis in the value for the dialog condition. I was able to resolve my error by wrapping the value in quotes.

```
//example
var docuwareEntity = new DocuwareEntity
            {
                Id = 6,
                Chapitre = "Chapter",
                SousChapitre = "\"Some (SousChapitre)\"", //this value is wrapped in quote
                FileCabinetId = "FILE_CABINET_ID",
                Type = "DocumentType"
            };
```